# C# check multiple controls

Tags: c#

I have a simple C# WindowsForm application for a TicTacToe game.
So I have the following buttons, with their names:

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2 
A3 B3 C3
```

And I'm performing the following check to determine if theres a winner:

```
(
  (
    ((A1.Text == A2.Text) && (A2.Text == A3.Text) && A2.Text != "") // columns
    ||((B1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == B3.Text) && B2.Text != "")
    ||((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text) && C2.Text != "")
  )
  ||
  (
    ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text) && B1.Text != "") // rows
    || ((A2.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C2.Text) && B2.Text != "")
    || ((A3.Text == B3.Text) && (B3.Text == C3.Text) && B3.Text != "")
  )
  ||
  (
    ((A1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C3.Text) && B2.Text != "") // diagonals
    || ((C1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == A3.Text) && B2.Text != "")
  )
)
```

However this syntax seems inefficient, due the alot of repetition and probably redundant coding. 
So could anyone **suggest how can I group and check indivudual sets of controls** (in this case buttons) ?

My instinct tells me about creating an array like this:

```
Button[,] arr =
{
  { A1, B1, C1 }, { A2, B2, C2 }, { A3, B3, C3 }, // rows
  { A1, A2, A3 }, { B1, B2, B3 }, { C1, C2, C3 }, // columns
  { A1, B2, C3}, { C1, B2, A3 }, // diagonals
};
```

But I have no idea how to iterate through it and perform the equality checks.

Comment: You should have a backing data source that _drives_ the controls.  Maybe a 3x3 array of `TicTacToeSquare` enum `[X, O, Unknown]`